# How to remove a directory and its contents using NSFileManager

Tags: iphone, objective-c

New to Objective C. I have created a few directories which contain pdf files for an iPhone app. How can I delete a directory and its contents using NSFileManager?

Do I need to loop through and remove the contents first? Any code samples would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To start off, it would be wise to look through Apple's `NSFileManager` documentation for the iPhone: [NSFileManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1408573-removeitematpath?language=objc). Second, look at `NSFileManager`'s `-removeItemAtPath:error:` method and its documentation. That's what you're looking for.

Comment: If I pass a directory to -removeItemAtPath:error: will it also remove the contents? Sounds like a silly question, but the only other example I have found delete the contents of the directory first.

Comment: Yes, it will, and if you are ever in doubt about something, just set up a tiny test program to see if it does.

Comment: @ItaiFerber Trying it is fine, but asking results in a searchable, crowd-sourced answer being posted here on the web. So: asking first has its advantages.

Comment: @GregMaletic My comment was meant to reinforce the idea that if one is ever in doubt about Apple's documentation or about any answers on SO, self-verification can really help clarify what's going on. Nothing more, nothing less. :)

Answer (score 39):

Heres some code I use that Ive edited to suit the question

```
- (NSMutableString*)getUserDocumentDir {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSMutableString *path = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[paths objectAtIndex:0]];
    return path;
}


- (BOOL) createMyDocsDirectory
{
    NSMutableString *path = [self getUserDocumentDir];
    [path appendString:@"/MyDocs"];
    NSLog(@"createpath:%@",path);
    return [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:path
                                           withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                           attributes:nil 
                                           error:NULL];
}

- (BOOL) deleteMyDocsDirectory 
{
    NSMutableString *path = [self getUserDocumentDir];
    [path appendString:@"/MyDocs"];
    return [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:nil];
}
```

Comment: how to delete specific set of images?

Comment: Consider stringByAppendingPathComponent instead of appendString!

Comment: @Bazinga check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/67891146/3124756

Answer (score 1):

You can get document directory by using this:

```
NSString *directoryPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents/"];
```

** Remove full directory path by using this:

```
BOOL success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:directoryPath error:nil];
if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"Directory delete failed");
}
```

** Remove the contents of that directory using this:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];    
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:directoryPath]) {
            NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath:directoryPath];
            NSString *documentsName;
            while (documentsName = [dirEnum nextObject]) {
                NSString *filePath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingString:documentsName];
                BOOL isFileDeleted = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
                if(isFileDeleted == NO) {
                    NSLog(@"All Contents not removed");
                    break;
                }
            }
            NSLog(@"All Contents Removed");
        }
```

** You can edit `directoryPath` as per your requirement.

Comment: There is a bug in your method to delete the contents of a directory.  The statement `NSString *filePath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingString:documentsName];` in the while loop will not work. One must insert a `/` before `documentsname`. So the statement should be `NSString *filePath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@",documentsName];` OR even better use `NSString *filePath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:documentsName];`.