# Delete a folder and its subfolders in Objective-C / C

Tags: objective-c, ios

How can I delete a folder and its subfolders in Objective-C / C on iOS?

Answer (score 77):

You can use `NSFileManager` :

```
BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:pathToFolder error:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664694/how-to-remove-a-directory-and-its-contents-using-nsfilemanager/67891146#67891146). You can check the link or follow the answer I've provided:
You can get document directory by using this:

```
NSString *directoryPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents/"];
```

** Remove full directory path by using this:

```
BOOL success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:directoryPath error:nil];
if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"Directory delete failed");
}
```

** Remove the contents of that directory using this:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];    
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:directoryPath]) {
            NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath:directoryPath];
            NSString *documentsName;
            while (documentsName = [dirEnum nextObject]) {
                NSString *filePath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingString:documentsName];
                BOOL isFileDeleted = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
                if(isFileDeleted == NO) {
                    NSLog(@"All Contents not removed");
                    break;
                }
            }
            NSLog(@"All Contents Removed");
        }
```

** You can edit `directoryPath` as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [paths[0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Videos"];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
    BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:nil];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Directory delete failed");
    }
}
```