# Can the application be reset programmatically in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, initialization, reset

Is there any simple way to reset the application in programmatically?

I can erase each folder separately but I thought there is got to be another good way.

Is it possible that erasing all files(database, caches, and user created files ..) like the application initial state?

Comment: better to delete app and install again

Comment: You, as being the author, need to do this yourself. AFIK iOS doesn't have a mechanism that keeps track what you all create. You can remove (recursively) your root (user) folder and all that resides there. The defaults (as config settings) you need to reset yourself. Should be fairly simple.

Comment: @himanth no, thanks but I need it with no user action.

Comment: @Roger Oh, there is no way to do that. thanks maybe I need to do this myself.

Comment: @Charlotte check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664694/how-to-remove-a-directory-and-its-contents-using-nsfilemanager